# I am not able to pause TTS(specifically Earcon)

Tags: java, android

when an Earcon(part of TTS) is running I want to be able to pause it in between and resume it from the moment i paused it. What can i do to achieve it?

I am working on Android Studio using Java. I am able to pause TTS easily but its Earcon module is not pausing in the middle of speaking.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ques; i++) {
    if (!gameRunning) break;
    // whistle.start();
    textToSpeech.playEarcon("[bark]", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    Log.d(TAG, "level3: bark started");
    //while (whistle.isPlaying()) ;
    while (textToSpeech.isSpeaking());
    Log.d(TAG, "level3: bark over");
}
```

I expect .playEarcon to pause when I want but instead it completes the whole loop and then it stops... i want it to stop in the loop itself and run the loop again for Earcon.